# how to get the non-removed array element on using splice method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and using splice to remove an element from an array, however I always get the removed array.
ex:

```
let myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'sturgeon']
myFish.splice(-1,1) // goves o/p ['sturgeon']
```

however I want the remaining array element
expected o/p:

```
['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin']
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: The non-removed are in your array, `myFish`, here.

Comment: `splice` changes the Array, that's why it returns that which has been removed.

Comment: `slice`, on the other hand, gives you part of the array without changing the array.

Comment: @iAmOren wouldn't one answer be better then three comments? :-)

Comment: so this is basically a string that I have: ```str= "Hello_Worksl_SHARED"``` and I'm doing split() and then splice- ```str.split("_").splice(-1,1)``` however if I need to access the non-removed array, I need to do 2 steps: ```let a = str.split("_")``` then ```a.splice(-1,1)``` and then access ```a```. is there a way I can do everything in 1 step?

Comment: @JanStránský, correct!  And - Done!  up-vote?!? :)

Comment: @user1234 Depending on your needs, you can wrap the code into a function returning what you needs. What parts of the array are you `splice`ing? Always `(-1,1)`? In that case, "plain" `slice` would work

Comment: yesI always want to return the last element of the array after the split

Comment: Thanks guys, youre great! for your help

Comment: Using your example of `myFish` - what do you want and in what variable?
Do you want `myFish` to be one element shorter, or unchanged?
If one element shorter, do you want a copy of the origianl?
Do you want to store the last element, or discard it?

Comment: myFish to be shorter, i think answer you gave works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str="Hello_Worksl_SHARED", splitStr, strMinusEnd;
strMinusEnd=(splitStr=str.split("_")).slice(0,-1);

console.log("str="+str);
console.log("splitStr="+splitStr);
console.log("strMinusEnd="+strMinusEnd);
```

---

Before your comment with extra info:

The non-removed are in your array, `myFish`.

`splice` changes the Array, that's why it returns that which has been removed.

`slice`, on the other hand, gives you part of the array without changing the array.

---

I'm not sure what you want, so here is everything:

```js
var str="Hello_Worksl_SHARED";
var arrFromStr, arrMinusEnd, endItem;

[arrFromStr, arrMinusEnd, endItem] = 
  str.split("_")
  .reduce(
    (acc, cv, idx, arr) => {
      if(idx<arr.length-1) acc[1].push(cv);
      else {
        acc[0]=arr;
        acc[2]=cv;
      };
      return acc;
    },
    [null,[],[]]
  )
;

console.log("str=\""+str+"\"");
console.log("arrFromStr=");
console.log(arrFromStr);
console.log("arrMinusEnd=");
console.log(arrMinusEnd);
console.log("endItem=\""+endItem+"\"");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

We're using destructuring of an array.
Right-hand-side of the `=` returns an array of 3 elements.
Each of those are respectfully(?) assigned to the 3 variables on the left-hand-side of that `=`.

The `reduce` is spread over multiple lines for clarity.

Comment: If you want end and start instead of full `slice`d array, you can use slightly modified (but using same approach) `var str="Hello_Worksl_SHARED", end, start; end=(start=str.split("_")).splice(-1,1);` Maybe would be worth adding to the answer

Comment: @JanStránský, as more details about the desired output are unveiling, modifications are required...